# php and cron job questions, can I change one variable in php file from another php file?

Tags: php, cron

I have 3 questions that will greatly help me with my project that I am stuck on, after much narrowing down these are the resulted questions arised from solutions:

1. Can I use one php file to change a variable value in another php file, can these values be read also from one php file to another?
2. How can I use crob job to change variable values within my php code?
3. Lastly, can cron read variable values in my php files??? for Example, if statements that will decide what to trigger and how to trigger when cron time comes?

I am a little new at cron and going deeper into php and need all the exeprtise help. I cant use any CURL or frameworks.

Please prevent the hijacking of my topic, the data I want is simple change $variable=1 in filenameA.php to $variable=2 using filenameB.php

Comment: You should try to explain *what* you want to accomplish rather than *how* you think it needs to be done. Your description suggests that you want to alter dynamically your PHP source code and I don't think you really want that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a very good practice, but it's the simplest thing you can do:

You need three files: `my_script.php`, `my_cron_job.php`, and `my_data.txt`.

In the script that control's `$data` (this is called `my_cron_job.php`):

```
<?php
  $values = array(
              "some_key" => "some_value",
              "anything" => "you want"
              );

  file_put_contents("my_data.txt",serialize($values));
```

Running it will also create my_data.txt.

Then, in `my_script.php`:

```
<?php     
  $data = unserialize(file_get_contents("my_data.txt"));
  print_r($data);   //if you want to look at what you've got.
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what type of data you are exchanging between PHP files. I'm fairly new as well, but will see what the community thinks of my answer. (Criticism welcomed)

I would have my PHP files write my common data to a txt file. When the cron job executes the PHP files, the PHP files can access/write to the txt file with the common data.

Comment: I dont know if you know Twilio but Twilio is an application that allows you to call a 1800 number and when you do, a php script you have written handles the phone call so you can communicate with the user using the code uve written, in my case my php code is going to a on call schedule calendar on a website, reading from that calendar who is responsible for takign the calls that week, and connecting that person to the caller.
 
The people for the on call schedule change every week.

Comment: I so far have the part of script working where a user calls and is conencted to the representative for the week. But now whats needed is, if you want to not follow the usual procedure of conencting the call to the person on the on call schedule for a week, and you want to go irregular meaning for that week
 
you dont want to follow the on call schedule for the calls received by the caller, instead you want to pick who it should call for the week, and once that week ends go back to the usual process of following the on call schedule

Comment: +1 is my criticism.  You can also use the DB if you are already using one.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be describing a configuration file of some type.

I would recommend either an XML file or a database table.

For an XML file you could have something like:

```
<settings>
    <backup>
        <active>1</active>
        <frequency>daily</frequency>
        <script_file>backup.php</script_file>
    </backup>
    <reporting>
        <active>1</active>
        <frequency>weekly</frequency>
        <script_file>generate_report.php</script_file>
    </reporting>
    <time_chime>
        <active>1</active>
        <frequency>hourly</frequency>
        <script_file>ring_bell.php</script_file>
    </time_chime>
</settings>
```

then have some controller script that cron calls hourly that reads the XML file and calls the scripts accordingly.  Your crontab would look like:

```
0    *    *    *    *    php /path/to/script/cron_controller.php
```

and cron_controller.php would contain something like:

```
$run_time = time();

$cron_config = simplexml_load_file($conf_file_location);
if($cron_config === false) die('failed to load config file');

foreach($cron_config as $cron) {
    if($cron->active != 1) continue;  //cron must be active
    $run_script = false;

    switch((string) $cron->frequency) {
        case 'hourly':
            $run_script = true;
            break;
        case 'daily':
            if(date('H', $run_time) == '00') //is it midnight?
                $run_script = true;
            break;
        case 'weekly':
            if(date('w:H', $run_time) == '0:00') //is it sunday at midnight?
                $run_script = true;
            break;
    }

    if($run_script) {
        $script_file = (string) $cron->script_file;
        if(file_exists($script_file)) {
            echo "running $script_file\n";
            require($script_file);
        }
        else {
            echo "could not find $script_file\n";
        }
    }
}
```

and if you need to edit your configuration with php scripts you can use [SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) to do it, then just save it back to the original location with `$cron_config->saveXML($conf_file_location);`